Can brahmanas have enemies?
Can Brahmanas have enmity with others like kshatriyas? Or they should maintain nirvairatvam?

Not really, Brahma bhuta prasannatma.. one is free to do whatever one wants but he would be considered as a brahmana of a lower potency if he bears grudges or goes around making ememies. But someone like Parasurama would be an exception as Vishnu Himself acted through him.  A sample verse describing the qualities of a brahmana.  https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/9/29/
